# The error "clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"

Tags: clojure

In a Luminus app here's a part of an action which produces an error:

```
                 some-var (if (rem total-records page-size)
                                     (quot total-records page-size)
                                     (+ 1 (quot total-records page-size)))
```

the error being `clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`. And this doesn't:

```
some-var 123
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that one of your variables `total-pages` and/or `page-size` is not a number but a seq whereas `rem` and `quot` functions require all its arguments to be numbers. Try to print it to console to check which one it is.

There is also another issue in your `if` expression: you want to use number value to test for truthiness. In Clojure any number value (including 0) is truthy (strictly speaking only `nil`and `false` values are treated as falsehood) so you need to compare the result of `rem` to zero:

```
(if (zero? (rem a b)) 
  :truthy
  :falsey)
```

Comment: I have this `total-records (db/get-articles-total-count)` . How can I to get it to evaluate?

Comment: How your `get-articles-total-count` looks like? It seems it returns a seq instead of bare number.

Comment: it returns a number, it's "select count(*)..."

Comment: Print the results of `(db/get-articles-total-count)` and I think you will see it is either a vector of hashmaps or a single hashmap.